# Wifi: Connected to Network, but No Internet

Tags: networking, wireless, 20.04, iwlwifi

**Summary:**
My computer connects to the router's SSID, but I have no internet - at least via Browser.

**Details:**
I just installed 20.04 (was using 18.04 without issue).  The SSID (along with other SSID's that aren't mine) is found.  When I check on Wi-Fi settings, the Signal Strength is 'Good.'

When I look at Additional Drivers, the status under the device model Intel Corporation: Wireless 8265 / 8275 is "This device is not working."  The only option available below is "Continue using a manually installed driver."  Both "Using iwlwifi driver backport in DKMS format from packport-iwlwifi-dkms (open source)" and "Do not use the device" are grey and I cannot select either of those.

I was able to update and upgrade Ubuntu 20.04 via terminal after the installation, but the delay in downloading was significant.  I'm able to `ping 8.8.8.8` (google) in the terminal and get `64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=54 time=192 ms.`

Ubuntu Software application isn't usable, and I can't browse via Firefox that came installed.

**Equipment:**
Wifi Device: Intel 8265 / 8275
Computer:  Intel NUC7i5BNK

I'm happy to provide any additional details.

*May 22 update:*
I tried running Ubuntu 18.04 via USB drive, but wifi wouldn't load most pages (same problem as 20.04).  I just connected via ethernet on installed 20.04 (not a long term solution, but will get me by for now).  Ethernet works perfectly.  So I assume that eliminates DNS issues (not my area of expertise).
Anyone have any thoughts?  I'm completely stumped.

Comment: You are connected to internet. But you have some DNS problems.

Comment: I like the theory that DNS is the issue.  It would explain why some pages load and most don't.  After a fair bit a research, I tried editing /etc/systemd/resolved.conf and adding 'DNS=8.8.8.8 2001:4860:4860::8888' and 'FallbackDNS=8.8.4.4 2001:4860:4860::8844'  I then rebooted.  Sadly, that didn't resolve it.  Any suggestions on troubleshooting DNS?

Comment: Continuing to think through it, would DNS issues cause the status I'm seeing in Additional Drivers for Intel wireless 8265 / 8275: "This device is not working" and "Do not use the device" is selected even though it is grey?

Comment: This is not driver related.

Answer (score 0):

You can test the DNS issue theory by opening terminal and ping google.com instead of the IP address. If there are DNS issues, this shouldn't work. Have you tried updating and upgrading packages?

If it is the DNS, you should be able to connect to a VPN through the terminal and then be able to use your browser.

Speaking of browsers: have you checked your settings there to make sure your connection settings don't include a proxy? Here is described how to check the connection settings in Firefox: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/connection-settings-firefox

Comment: I pinged google.com from the terminal with success:  "64 bytes from mia09s17-in-x0e.1e100.net …. time=22.0ms."  However, I'm able to load Google.com from Firefox.  So I tried a sight that I cannot load from Firefox, WeatherBug.com.  The ping via terminal was successful "64 bytes from server-13-32-86-61.mia3.r.cloudfront.net....time=61.7ms."  I also checked the network settings in Firefox.  I changed it from 'Use system proxy settings' to 'No proxy.'  I closed and reloaded Firefox.  That didn't fix it.  I don't think it's a Firefox issue because I can't search for new apps in Ubuntu Software.

Comment: PS - all packages are updated and upgraded.  I just re-ran 'sudo apt-get update' and the connection to canonical took ~30+ seconds to establish.